# Sort array by order according to another array

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have an object that is being returned from a database like this: `[{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]`.  I have another array which specified the order the first array should be sorted in, like this: `[2,3,1]`.

I'm looking for a method or algorithm that can take in these two arrays and return `[{id:2},{id:3},{id:1}]`.  Ideally it should be sort of efficient and not n squared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want linear time, first build a hashtable from the first array and then pick items in order by looping the second one:

```js
data = [{id:5},{id:2},{id:9}]
order = [9,5,2]

hash = {}
data.forEach(function(x) { hash[x.id] = x })

sorted = order.map(function(x) { return hash[x] })

document.write(JSON.stringify(sorted))
```

Answer (score 3):

```js
    function sortArrayByOrderArray(arr, orderArray) {
        return arr.sort(function(e1, e2) {
            return orderArray.indexOf(e1.id) - orderArray.indexOf(e2.id);
        });
    }

    console.log(sortArrayByOrderArray([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}], [2,3,1]));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example, the objects are initially sorted by `id`, which makes the task pretty easy. But if this is not true in general, you can still sort the objects in linear time according to your array of `id` values.

The idea is to first make an index that maps each `id` value to its position, and then to insert each object in the desired position by looking up its `id` value in the index. This requires iterating over two arrays of length `n`, resulting in an overall runtime of `O(n)`, or linear time. There is no asymptotically faster runtime because it takes linear time just to read the input array.

```js
function objectsSortedBy(objects, keyName, sortedKeys) {
  var n = objects.length,
      index = new Array(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  // Get the position of each sorted key.
    index[sortedKeys[i]] = i;
  }
  var sorted = new Array(n);
  for (var i = 0; i < n; ++i) {  // Look up each object key in the index.
    sorted[index[objects[i][keyName]]] = objects[i];
  }
  return sorted;
}

var objects = [{id: 'Tweety', animal: 'bird'},
               {id: 'Mickey', animal: 'mouse'},
               {id: 'Sylvester', animal: 'cat'}],
    sortedIds = ['Tweety', 'Mickey', 'Sylvester'];

var sortedObjects = objectsSortedBy(objects, 'id', sortedIds);

// Check the result.
for (var i = 0; i < sortedObjects.length; ++i) {
  document.write('id: '+sortedObjects[i].id+', animal: '+sortedObjects[i].animal+'<br />');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To my understanding, sorting is not necessary; at least in your example, the desired resulting array can be generated in linear time as follows.

```
var Result;
for ( var i = 0; i < Input.length; i++ )
{
    Result[i] = Input[Order[i]-1];
}
```

Here `Result` is the desired output, `Input` is your first array and `Order` the array containing the desired positions.

Comment: This assumes that the original array is already sorted by the `id` values and they're consecutive.

Comment: You are right, but the provided example has both of these properties and it's not stated differently elsewhere that they may be violated.

Answer (score 0):

```
var objArray = [{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}];
var sortOrder = [2,3,1];

var newObjArray = [];
for (i in sortOrder) {
    newObjArray.push(objArray[(sortOrder[i]) - 1])
};
```

Comment: obj array cant be indexed by sortorder

Comment: My mistake. I thought the question was the 2nd array had the positions of the sort, not the id values.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create new array and push the value from second array in?? Correct me if i wrong

```
array1 = [];
array2 = [2,3,1];

for ( var i = 0; i < array2 .length; i++ )
{
    array1.push({
         id : array2[i]
     })
}
```